# Get a count of a set when a condition is met

Tags: functions, inequality

This feels like an easy question, but I can't seem to hammer it down.  Just like $\Sigma$ can be used to sum over several items, it there a way to count them?

The simple example, is that I want to get a count of all the years in a sample that are prior to 2008.

This is what I want to do:

$${\rm YearsBefore2008} = \sum_{y=2006}^{2010} y < 2008$$

But I can't exactly have an inequality in a $\sum$ statement.

- Is there a count symbol that counts 1 if `true`?
- Is there a mathematical way to convert the result of an inquality to 1 if true, and 0 if false so I can sum like normal?
- Is there a better way to do this in general?

Comment: You could use an Iverson bracket. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket

Comment: Or the indicator function http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function